# Alternative content with Adobe Edge Animate in HTML?

Tags: adobe-edge

I have this Adobe Edge Content by a client.

THe HTML Code is

```html
<div id="Stage" class="EDGE-XXXXXXXXX">

</div>
```

What should I do to have an alternative content for IE 8 and below?

If I just insert some content inside the div, it is not overwritten by Edge.

I know, there is kind of down-level support in Edge, but I don't own Edge myself, so I cannot try out.

So what is the actual HTML markup that uses the  down-level support feature?

---

### edit

`<noscript>` won't work, because Internet Explorer 8 *has* JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the *_edgePreload.js file navigate to the end of the file where it says:

```
})("EDGE-XXXXXXXX");
```

where the ID is the same as in your HTML source. IMMEDIATELY before this exact string (there may be some spaces) add a new variable as follows (ensure dlContent isn't already assigned with a similar stanza, and if it is then replace that assignation - I'm guessing your js files are minified so this will not look the same as your version, but it'll still work when pasted into the file!):

```
dlContent={
   dom: [
   {
      id:'Poster',
      type:'image',
      tag:'img',
      linkURL:"URL/to/some/content",
          //This line can be omitted if no linking of the image is desired
      linkTarget:"_top",//omit this line if the above line has been omitted
      rect:['0','0','100%','100%','auto','auto'],
          //values in order: x-pos, y-pos, width, height, ?, ?
          // not sure what the two auto values correspond to right now
          // the rectangle is the "viewport" into what would be the animation in better browsers.
      fill:["rgba(0,0,0,0)",'/path/to/an/image.jpg','0px','0px']
          // values in order: background colour and alpha transparency, an image to use, image position x and y within the rectangle defined above.
   }]};
```

Comment: I know this works, because I've taken it from a client website where this is being used live. I unfortunately cannot link you to the client's site due to contractual obligations with my employer.

Comment: I'd wish Adobe had some documentation on this.

Comment: I'll give it try. Cannot test at the moment. But seems sensible.